# Greek & Latin words from ANE languages excluding Biblical Hebrew

Tags: etymology, greek

Seeing [this question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/17637/are-there-ancient-greek-words-descended-from-sumerian) made me curious if there's an already-compiled list of words of Ancient Near Eastern origin, hopefully excluding all those borrowed from the Hebrew Bible or other Hebrew/Aramaic works through translation (though I'm not picky if they're included, too). Also welcome would be more unusual borrowings (Chinese, Sanskrit, Berber, non-IE European languages).

I could, separately, search [de Vaan](http://www.brill.com/etymological-dictionary-latin) and [Beekes](http://www.brill.com/etymological-dictionary-greek-2-vols), but that would be time consuming, and I'm hoping that something already exists. Also, no Bernal, please.

Comment: De Vaan unfortunately excludes loanwords entirely, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: @TKR No, I think you're right. I couldn't remember if he included some or not, but thinking about it now, I don't think he does. What a bummer.

Comment: Beekes does have an index of non-IE words.

Comment: @fdb Beekes has that wonderful section in the beginning on the Pre-Greek substrate, but I don't see anywhere here where he has a separate section on all Greek words of non-IE descent, even if the Pre-Greek substrate was non-IE. I am thankful though that he mentions whenever someone has a plausible (even if unlikely) derivation from another language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classic work is: É. Masson, Recherches sur les plus anciens emprunts sémitiques en grec, Paris 1967.

Now also this: https://www.academia.edu/5020261/Les_emprunts_s%C3%A9mitiques_en_grec_ancien_%C3%A9tude_m%C3%A9thodologique_et_exemples_myc%C3%A9niens

Comment: Can you give a brief description of the book and maybe give a link to additional information (or even a freely available version if there is one)? Also, a couple of example words would be great. This source sounds promising, but it would be good to give an idea of what to expect from the book.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta. Masson's book does not seem to be on the internet, but I have added a link to the more recent study by Bourguignon.